# Conditional probability question - Horse Racing Specific

Tags: probability

question here which is bugging me and i'm fairly sure is easy to answer.

In the below example, lets assume this is a horse race with 10 runners (horse A-Horse K). 
[image]

Let's say we want to work out the pre race odds of horses A, B, and C all finishing in the top 3.

As per the image i've multiplied A, B, and C together to get 20% to give a 1 in 5 chance of this happening. However the part i am struggling with, is to understand if this is the correct way of working it out. eg. if A and B both place, is the percentage of C placing still 50% or do i need to apply a different calculation to understand the true odds of A, B, and C happening.

Thanks in advance.

-- Note, if you can not see image, horse A has a 4/6 chance of finishing in the top 3. Horse B has a 3/5 chance, and horse C has a 1/2 chance.
Hence 4/6*3/5*1/2 = 12/60 = 1/5

Comment: So as I see it, you have three given probabilities
$$
P(A) = \frac{2}{3} \qquad P(B)=\frac{3}{5} \qquad P(C) = \frac{1}{2}
$$
The first question is, what is the probability $P(A \cap B \cap C)$? The important question to consider is, are $A$, $B$ and $C$ independent? If they are, then
$$P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A) \cdot P(B) \cdot P(C)$$. After this, you wanted to consider the probability
$$
P(C | A \cap B)
$$
Again, one would have to use independence for this.

Comment: You are assuming that the events A is in the top $3$, B is in the top $3$, C is in the top $3$ are independent, which seems most unlikely.

Comment: I agree with @saulspatz. Imagine that $A$ has come first. What is the probability that $B$ is either second or third? It's surely not the same probability that $B$ is first, second, or third, agreed? Therefore, I believe that the events are not independent. In this case, you basically cannot formally solve this problem unless you know the conditional probabilities.

Answer (score 2):

.. you have 11 horses, not 10 ...

But to the point: No, you can't just multiply these individual probabilities!

For example, to figure out the probability that both $A$ and $B$ finish in the top $3$, you need to use the probability that $B$ finishes in the top three *given* that $A$ finishes in the top three.

The general formula for the conjunction of events is:

$$P(A \cap B)= P(A) \cdot P(B|A)$$

So, to figure out the probability that both $A$ and $B$ finish in the top $3$, you need to calculate $P(A)\cdot P(B|A)$, rather than $P(A) \cdot P(B)$.

As some of the Commentors point out, you can only use $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$ if events $A$ and $B$ are independent. But, clearly they are not: If $A$ finishes in the top 3, then obviously $B$ will have a smaller chance of (also) finishing in the top 3 than if $A$ does not finish in the top 3. Thus, $P(B|A)<P(B|A')$.

As to $P(B)$: this is the probability of $B$ finishing in the top three without knowing whether $A$ finishes in the top 3. As such, it is kind of the aggregate of considering events where $A$ does finish in the top three as well as events where $A$ does not. Therefore, $P(B)$ will lie somewhere in between $P(B|A)$ and $P(B|A')$ . That is: $P(B|A)<P(B)<P(B|A')$

In short, the point is: while you know $P(B)$, this is not the same as $P(B|A)$, and as already indicated, it is the latter that you need to calculate $P(A \cap B)$

Finally, let me give one more perspective that might be a bit more intuitive. As I already explained, the conditional probability of a horse finishing in the top three *given* that one or more other horses are already in the top three is always going to be smaller than simply the individual probability of that horse being in the top three. Hence, your method of multiplying the individual probabilities will always overestimate the probability of several horses getting into the top three. Indeed, note how you end up with a $0.2$ probability of horses $A$, $B$, and $C$ making up the top three .... just looking at the probabilities and using your common number sense, it should be clear that that is far too big.

Indeed, we can take this to the extreme to really show that what you are doing cannot possibly be correct. Consider the probability of horses $A$, $B$, $C$, *and* $D$ finishing in the top three. That is of course impossible, so the probability should be $0$. But using your method of just multiplying the individual probabilities, you get a non-zero probability!

Comment: Good example in the last paragraph!

Comment: It's a very minor technicality, but if horses A and B dead heat, horses C and D dead heat, and horses E and F dead heat for 1st, 2nd and 3rd places respectively, then all six "finish in the top three".  For a bookmaker then, horses A and B pay out in full (as places; they pay out half as joint winners) and horses C and D pay out half as places, and horses A, B, C and D would be considered the top three finishers :)

Comment: @postmortes Huh! I had no idea that could happen. Learn something every day! :)

Comment: My pleasure:  the usual rule of thumb we had is that the impossible happens twice a year in horse racing.  It comes down to there being at least 40k horses being raced a year, so the outliers happen

Comment: @postmortes Ha, that's great!  Nice example of how the assumptions and idealizations we make in math don't always reflect reality :)